# Error response 400 "Request contains an invalid argument" after the standard Slides manipulation

Tags: google-apps-script, add-on, google-slides, google-workspace-add-ons

Recently my scripts started to fail after the first run. In other words: 1st run succeeds, the next fail, and the error 400 "Request contains an invalid argument" can be seen in the Dev Tools of a browser.

Here is a small code example that reliably reproduces the issue:

**appscript.json**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Riga",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",

  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "A simple test script",
      "logoUrl": "https://www.gstatic.com/images/icons/material/system/1x/pets_black_48dp.png"
    },
      "slides": {
        "homepageTrigger": {
          "runFunction": "onSlidesEditorHomepage"
        }
      }
  }
}
```

**code.gs**

```
function onSlidesEditorHomepage() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(
        CardService.newCardSection().addWidget(
          CardService.newDecoratedText()
          .setText("Slides...")
          .setButton(
            CardService.newTextButton()
              .setText('Move a slide')
              .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName('onMoveClick'))
              .setTextButtonStyle(CardService.TextButtonStyle.FILLED)
              .setDisabled(false)
          )
        )
      );
  return card.build();

}

function onMoveClick() {
  let p = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  let slides = p.getSlides();
  slides[1].move(0);  // move the 2nd slide to the beginning

  // appendSlide function hangs in the same way
  // let p = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();
  // let slides = p.getSlides();
  // p.appendSlide(slides[0]);    // inserts a copy of the slide

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNotification(CardService.newNotification()
      .setText("The slides has been moved"))
      .build();
}
```

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Open a Slides presentation with 5 slides
2. Click the "Move a slide" button for the 1st time
3. Click the "Move a slide" button for the 2nd time
4. Click the "Move a slide" button for the 3nd time

The 1st time a slide is moved. **Any consecutive runs fail with a console error: 400 "Request contains an invalid argument".**

Note, that this and similar code worked on September 2021.

**Update:** I also submitted this bug to the Google Slides issue tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210299318 but such issues stay there for years without any fixes or workarounds. I hope to find some fix or at least a workaround.

Comment: "but such issues stay there for years without any fixes or workarounds" this is true for some issues not for all of them. Starring an issue helps to tell Google how many people are interested on it but there are other factors considered to "fix" it. The good thing about your issue is that it is already "Assigned" (many issues never reach this status)

Answer (score 1):

This is a reproducible bug that has already been reported via IssueTracker (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/210299318).

If anyone else encounters the same bug, I would strongly suggest upvoting it by clicking the star next to the issue number.

Comment: Is this an answer? I submitted that issue. I can't wait Google's standard 2 years until they fix basic stuff. And please upvote it, as it currently has 0 upvotes.

Comment: @MarisB. You should mention that the issue on the question. Regarding your impatience, there is nothing that we can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

As regular developers, I think that unfortunately there isn't anything other than posting an issue / starring an existing issue that we can do to fix Google Apps Script services problems like this.

Things to try

1. Use the Properties Service to store / retrieve the active presentation Id and instead of `let p = SlidesApp.getActivePresentation();` use `let p = SlidesApp.openById(id);`
2. Change the script owner, move the script to / out of a Shared Drive.
3. Make a copy of the script. You might use the same Google Cloud project, just update the Google Apps Script project and version number
4. Use the old runtime (Rhino) instead of the default one (Chrome V8).
   NOTES: The old runtime doesn't support `let` and some other JavaScript changes introduced on ECMASCRIPT-2016. For the code shown in the question replacing `let` by `var` looks to be the easier / more convenient  way to proceed. For detailed instructions see https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/v8-runtime#enabling_the_rhino_runtime
5. Try using the [Advanced Slides Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/slides) instead of the Slides (Basic) Service.

Comment: Thanks for suggestions! 1-3 doesn't work. I tried that already. Number 4 and 5 are not options for me, as there is already large codebase using all new stuff (V8) and the old Slides class. Most probably we are abandoning Google Workspace, because the issue is so severe like `a = b + c` stopped working. Also, as nobody cares, there must be zero Apps Script users, and this is a huge risk that something will break in future and no one will fix it.

Comment: @MarisB. Thanks for your reply.